# c# UWP scan for music files

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, universal

I am implementing a music player for windows 10, and i am in a bit of a pickle at the library phase.

I am scanning for all the files in music library (plus optional folders the user selects) and i need to also get their tags (only need the title and artist, don't need complex details).

The problem is performance. Getting the music properties cost ALOT if you have a large media library. At the moment i am doing the following:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var files = await StorageHelper.GetFiles(KnownFolders.MusicLibrary);
                List<LocalAudio> tempList = new List<LocalAudio>();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    MusicProperties properties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();

                    var title = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(properties.Title) ? file.Name : properties.Title;
                    var artist = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(properties.Artist) ? file.Path : properties.Artist;
                    tempList.Add(new LocalAudio() { Title = title, FilePath = file.Path, Artist = artist, Duration = properties.Duration });
                    if (tempList.Count > 50)
                    {
                        await AddToLibrary(tempList);
                        tempList.Clear();
                    }
                }
                await AddToLibrary(tempList);
                tempList.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log exception here
            }
        });
    }

    private async Task AddToLibrary(List<LocalAudio> tempList)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in tempList)
            {
                this.LocalFiles.Add(item);
            }
        });
    }
```

Where "LocalAudio" is my audio model and this.LocalFiles is an ObservableCollection.
Also, the StorageHelper.GetFiles(StorageFolder) method returns an IEnumerable of StorageFiles (music files) (it's a recursive method to go in depth).

I am adding batches of 50 files on the dispatcher thread so i won't block the UI (i know, even if it is an async method running in a task that i started by fire-and-forget it still blocks the UI if i add them continuously...).

My question is: how can i optimize this better?
Any idea is good. I was thinking to scan them once and save the music properties (title, artist and duration) in a file and read that file on application start and just sync the filename with the data i have in that file (a dictionary or something and read the file and keep it in memory). Not sure how good this idea is.

Thank you for taking your time reading my silly questions :)

Comment: Optimisation questions are more suitable for CodeReview website...

Comment: Have you checked the official [Data virtualization sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDataVirtualization) in GitHub? I think you don't need to load all the info in one time, you can load them progressively. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yay, thanks, i'll look into it :)

Comment: However, seems like saving all the metadata in a file and loading it on startup behaves pretty good. Got 10.000 songs and once it scans all the ID3tags, it loads them from a single file and it seems to be working fast enough. Tried it on my tablet (has an intel i5 processor though and a SSD). Oh, and the songs are from the network, stored on an external HDD